# api.get_user with a list of users

Tags: python, tweepy

How do i get more than 1 user when using this list?

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

userID_list = ["JeffBezos", "BarackObama","elonmusk"]

for userxyz in userID_list:
    user_info = api.get_user(screen_name=userxyz)
    print(userxyz)

    name = user_info.name
    description = user_info.description
    followers_count = user_info.followers_count
    friends_count = user_info.friends_count

    user_info = {
        "Name":name,
        "Bios":description,
        "followers_count":followers_count,
        "friends_count":friends_count,
    }
print(user_info)
```

It only gives out the last user in the list, in my example "elonmusk".

```
{'Name': 'Elon Musk', 'Bios': '', 'followers_count': 64382297, 'friends_count': 104}
```

How do i get the other 2 users?

Comment: print the info inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you keep overwriting your `user_info` dictionary because you are reusing the same keys. One way you could deal with it (and there are many others) is to create a list to hold your dictionaries like so:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

userID_list = ["JeffBezos", "BarackObama","elonmusk"]
user_info_list = []
for userxyz in userID_list:
    user_info = api.get_user(screen_name=userxyz)
    print(userxyz)

    name = user_info.name
    description = user_info.description
    followers_count = user_info.followers_count
    friends_count = user_info.friends_count

    user_info = {
        "Name":name,
        "Bios":description,
        "followers_count":followers_count,
        "friends_count":friends_count,
    }
    user_info_list.append(user_info)
print(user_info_list)
```